# Use google maps embeds placemarks to change page content

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I just got an assigment were I have to embed a Google map, from a "My Places" map layer with some "PlaceMarks" on it.

This is pretty easy thanks to Google's nice built in function.

However, the problem is that it is suppose to change the content on the page that it is embeded on, when a guest click at one of the placemarkers. For example by calling some JavaScript functions.
Another way that will be okay is if there could be some test in the Placemarker description and in this, a link that when pressed, changes the content on the page embeded on, again by calling a JavaScript function of some kind.

Are there any nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to listen for the `click` event for the marker. This is some code from my site:

```
var marker =new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(searchResult.Latitude,searchResult.Longitude),
    map: googleMap,
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    //Function called when user clicks on the marker.
    //change page content here.
});
```

You could use an infoWindow to display whatever you need:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infoWindow.setContent("Content shown in infowindow above the map marker.");
    infoWindow.open(googleMap,marker);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
I don't understand where to put this? At the moment i just use the standard <iframe> embed.
I suppose you don't?

Comment: @Bjarkes I'm using the javascript library for google maps: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html. I run this code after setting up the map, in the pageLoad function for the page. I don't understand what you are doing with iframes, but I think that it is not possible to do more advanced things in that way.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
I just used the standard way to make embed by coping the html code with iframe from Maps.google.com. I will try to use the javascrupt library instead :)